# nsprcomp(): enforcing non-negativity for principal component analysis in R

Tags: r, pca

My goal is to do a **non-negative** PCA using `nsprcopm()` (*version 0.5.1.2* ) on my data and extract the values of PCs. I do it as follows in *R version 3.5.0*:

```
nnpca <- nsprcomp(mydata[,10:16], center = T, scale. = T, nneg = T)
```

The key is that I need to enforce **non-negativity** (because in the next step I will be using `glm(..., family = Gamma())`, and `glm` does not accept negative values with Gamma)

The problem is that `nsprcopm()` produces negative values for PCs. Here is a snapshot of the `nnpca$x`:
[image]

Any idea??! Is this is a bug for `nsprcomp()` or what? Am I missing something?!

Comment: Please provide data for a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/2359523), although if this is more stats than coding, may do better at [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, and just put it here for future reference if anybody encounters similar problem:

The problem arises from the argument `center = T`. When `True`, `nsprcomp` tries to shift all PCs so that they are around the center of coordinate. This will inevitably make some PCs negative (even though the original values are positive).

It can be overcome by `center = F`